# Xampp apache crashed php rar

Tags: php

I have rar extensions installed on php using xampp go-pear

It shown in php info that rar is enabled.

My code is following

```
<?php
$rar_file = rar_open('htdocs.rar') or die("Can't open Rar archive");

$entries = rar_list($rar_file);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo 'Filename: ' . $entry->getName() . "\n";
    echo 'Packed size: ' . $entry->getPackedSize() . "\n";
    echo 'Unpacked size: ' . $entry->getUnpackedSize() . "\n";

    $entry->extract('C:/xampp/htdocs');
}

rar_close($rar_file);

?>
```

rar_open causes apache to crash. if i comment out rar_open, apache wont crash and run as normal.

Anyone know what make it crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open bug [here](http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=15864&edit=1) that describes the issue you're having. Fixing this should be a simple PECL library upgrade.

> Current CVS version includes 3.7.8; if you have an older one, you might
>   want to wait for PECL Win32 builds to reappear and try with newer
>   version of the extension.

Comment: Unfortunately pecl4win.php.net (which is where the Windows PECL builds appear) is down for the moment (not sure when they'll be bringing it back up either).